# RAM consumption regarding cores/

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I am working on a 31 ,available, Go of RAM, 12 cores Linux KUbuntu computer.
I produce simulations which calculate functions over 4 dimensions (x,y,z,t).
I define my dimensions as arrays that I numpy.meshgrid for use. So, for each point of time, I calculate for each point x,y,z the result. It comes as heavy calculations with heavy data.

First, I learned how to use it with only one core. It works well and whatever are the size of my "boxs" ( x,y,z). Because of the fact I work a lot with Fourier transform, I define x,y,z,t as powers of 2 : 64,128,256,...
I can,without dificulties, go to x = y = z = t = 512, even if it takes a lot of time to run it (which makes sense). When I do that, I use around 20-30% of the available RAM of the computer. Great.

Then I wanted to use more cores. So I implemented this code :

```
import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)
results = [pool.apply_async(conv_green, args=(tstep, S_, )) for tstep in t]
```

So here I ask my script to use 8 cores, and define my results as the use of the function "conv_green" with the args "tstep,S_" all along t.

It works pretty well, use 8 cores as expected BUT I can not run any more simulations who use figures equal or above to 512 for x,y,z,t.

This is where my problem is. Technically, switching from the mono core system to multi chanegd nothing to the routine of my calculations. I do not understand why I have enough RAM for 512... in mono core and why,sudenly, when I switch to multi cores, computer does not even want to launch it ( and the error occurs at the" results = pool.apply ..."    line)

So if you guys know how this works and why I get this "treshold", thanks for helping me solving out !

Best regards.

PS : this is the error which pops out when it crashes with 512 in multi cores :

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "", line 1, in

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist
packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/home/alexis/Heat/Simu⁄Lecture Propre/Test Tkinter/Simulation N spots SCAN Tkinter.py", line 280, in 
    XYslice = array([p.get()[0] for p in results])

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value

SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call

Answer (score 1):

For multiprocessing in any language each thread will need private storage which it can write to without interference from the other threads. As soon as interference is possible the data structure has to be locked, which (in the worst case) takes us back to single threading.

It would appear that your large data structure is being copied for each of the threads, effectively multiplying your memory usage by eight when you have eight processors ... or up to 200% of your available RAM.

The best solution would be to prevent the unnecessary copying.

If that's not feasible then all you can do is limit the number of processors it can run on, four should be ok in your instance but make sure your machine has lots of swap space. The swap space also gives you some play to allow the virtual memory to exceed the physical RAM, if the "working set" is small enough you may be able to significantly exceed your physical RAM given enough swap.

Comment: Hi ! 
Thank you for your quick answer.

What you are saying is the conclusion I thaught of. There is certainly no mistery in my basic problem, and it is probably that simple.

Althought, I have no clue how to try to "prevent the unnecessary copying" :/ 

Do you know how I can estimate the swap space available on my computer ?

I am sorry that my questions are probably basics, but I am a noob for programmation, and python my first language

Comment: The linux command `free` will say how much ram and swap you have, `free -m` gives it in megabytes. As for the 'copying', Python hides memory management to "make things easy" which is great, usually. Other languages work differently, the language "C" throws it in your face (along with a lot of other details) and Fortran tries to do as little as possible which is why it's still used sometimes. For someone to help more with your Python you'll probably have to show more code; in a new question would be best.

Comment: Hi ! 
Learning the free -m command gave me a nice help ;) It confirmed to me what I thaught.

Is the way I used ( using multiprocessing from mp) the only one available to use multi cores with python ? 
Maybe there is another way which would deserve to give it a shot ?